# Oracle 18c Listener unable to start

Tags: oracle, windows-10, oracle18c

So I installed Oracle 18C XE and was able to connect to it. Comming back to it a few days later I can connect to it with SQLPlus using sys as Sysdba but am unable to connect with SQL Developer.

> Starting the listener through services results in an error saying the
>   OracleOraDB18Home1TNSListener service on local computer started then
>   stopped.

lstnrctl start from an admin cmd line gives the following errors:

> TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
>
> TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
>
> TNS-00515: Connect failed
>   because target host or object does not exist    64-bit Windows Error:
>   49: Unknown error

Ok sure - so i can ping the IP listed in tnsnames.ora but I can't telnet to 1521 on that ip
generated xe entry from tnsnames.ora

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.82)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
```

for good measure lstnrctl status is:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 02-JUN-2020 08:25:17

Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.82)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00505: Operation timed out
   64-bit Windows Error: 60: Unknown error
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

How can I resolve this? I just need to test an entity framework application on oracle.

I can kinda see that the IP address is wrong but this is a local installation for local app development only. Can I use Localhost?

I have updated tnsnames and listener as follows:

```
listener
    DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Fraser\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Fraser\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )



tnsnames
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

but SQL Developer now tells returns 'ora-12514, tns:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor'

connection properties are

```
username: sys as sysdba
PASSWORD: (confirmed with sql plus login)
hostname:localhost
port:1521
SID XE
Service name: XE
```

I get the same result using sid or service name radio button (sid is ora 12505 but it still references listener not knowing the SID in the connect descriptor)

lsnrctl is now:

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 02-JUN-2020 09:52:58

Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                02-JUN-2020 08:44:30
Uptime                    0 days 1 hr. 8 min. 32 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\Fraser\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\Fraser\product\18.0.0\diag\tnslsnr\SPR\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Is tnsnames malformed?

Comment: Your services not registered in listener,login as sysdba `alter system register` and check `lsnrctl status`

Comment: this removed the need to change the listener, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `localhost` if you only intend to connect to XE database instance from your local machine ... *but* it requires reconfiguring Oracle Net (listener) and Oracle XE database which is not so easy.

Comment: I tried localhost and the listener started, however now I am getting the error 'ra-12514, tns:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor' details added to the question.

Comment: You need to connect *locally* (without @localhost) to XE and verify parameter `show parameter local_listener` and if needed try to update hostname clause with `alter system set local_listener = .... (host=localhost)...`.

Comment: if this is tool difficult, it may be easier for you to try to modify `listener.ora` to put the IP address that worked with XE (of course this IP address must be configured on your Windows machine).

Comment: well now I am getting a invalid login for the sys as sysdba password i use for sqlplus BUT that is totally progress. Thanks!

Comment: If you're login on the same host you don't need to use password sys ie `sqlplus sys/password as sysdba` instead run this from elevated command prompt `sqlplus / as sysdba`